# XNA SoundEffect fails to be loaded from file

Tags: xna, xna-4.0, audio

I got a dictionary to store SoundEffects in, like:

```
public static Dictionary<string, SoundEffect> Hangok = new Dictionary<string, SoundEffect>();
```

I load sounds from files (normal .wav format), like:

```
GStatic.Hangok.Add(Azonosító, SoundEffect.FromStream(File.OpenRead(Azonosító)));
```

, where Azonosító was the filename.

All is just fine, files are loaded, except one; an exception is created:

> Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.

, what is not much of information for me. Could anyone explain this error message OR tell me why SoundEffect.FromStream fails to read? Why? When? Workaround?

Thanks in advance:
Péter

Comment: Is this happening only if you use non-english characters for filename? Could you try to load the same file, but use only english characters? If that doesn't work, make sure your .wav is either 8-bit or 16-bit audio (try adding it to Content Project just to see if it compiles).

Comment: It had no problem with the file name, and the bits. I checked content manager too, even tho' in a different program, because I did not want to polute my program with that. That gave error message too. Finally I tried something else (answer on this question) and it came out that the file was mono.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a complete, but working solution to this problem. "Answering my question" only, because it may be useful for other developers, who also have no idea what the problem may be.

```
    try
    {
      GStatic.Hangok.Add(Azonosító, SoundEffect.FromStream(File.OpenRead(Azonosító)));
    }
    catch
    {
      GStatic.Hangok.Add(Azonosító, new SoundEffect(File.ReadAllBytes(Azonosító), 11025, AudioChannels.Mono));
    }
```

And well: I got no idea WHY you can not load that file in the normal way and why you can load the way like in the exception handler. Having a file in mono should not be that big problem. If someone knows, please drop a note/comment.

Answer (score 1):

I use the ContentManager to load in SoundEffect's.  Place the wav file in the content project and it should just load in.

E.g.

```
SoundEffect s = Content.Load<SoundEffect>("name");
```

Comment: Thank you, but I do not want to use content manager. I prefer to load from file.